# latexmk unhappy with file that only contains filecontents block

Tags: latexmk, filecontents

Consider the file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{stuff.txt}
Some stuff
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

`latexmk` is unhappy with this file. Is there some way it could be placated? Error messages follow.

```
LaTeX Warning: Writing file `./stuff.txt'.

(./filecontents.aux) (./filecontents.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on filecontents.log.
=== TeX engine is 'pdfTeX'
Latexmk: Log file says no output from latex
Latexmk: For rule 'pdflatex', no output was made
Failure to make 'filecontents.pdf'
Latexmk: Errors, so I did not complete making targets
Collected error summary (may duplicate other messages):
  pdflatex: failed to create output file
Latexmk: Use the -f option to force complete processing,
 unless error was exceeding maximum runs, or warnings treated as errors.
```

Comment: Remember to tag it with latexmk (I think that is a valid tag)

Comment: the file gets written so not sure what else you want latexmk to do, as the message says you can use `-f` to make it warn a bit less,

Comment: What do you want to happen? Do you really want to use LaTeX to generate a static file stuff.txt, and nothing else? Why not just use stuff.txt in place of this file?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Yes, I just want it to generate static files. Why don't I just have the file? Two current reasons - (a) I can put multiple files with different names in there and (b) I can add comments. I could do something similar with a Python script, I presume, but in this context, TeX is more convenient.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I'm aware of the -f option, but force options always feel like a copout to me. The real issue is that it returns a failure (non-zero) value to Lua (which I'm calling it from) which correctly errors out at that point.

Comment: @FaheemMitha you could trap that in lua and not stop the lua run, or simply call latex instead of latexmk, or for that matter just write out the file without using tex at all, there seems to be some unstated underlying issue why you need to wrap this in such a complicated pipeline

Comment: If you must use latexmk for this, then generate one page of pdf to placate it. Latexmk -C will remove it.

Comment: Does it work if you put `\mkbox{}` between begin and end of document?

Answer (score 1):

It's not latexmk but pdflatex that has a problem. Since you have no body to the document (nothing between the \begin{document} and \end{document}) pdflatex cannot create a pdf. Simply add some text in the body and all will be well.

Comment: `pdflatex` itself doesn't have a problem, as far as I can tell. It just says "No pages of output." And I suppose I could add some text, but it would be a workaround.

Comment: @FaheemMitha : latexmk is just quitting because pdflatex couldn’t produce a pdf.

Comment: Right, but the lack of output in this particularly odd case is not actually an error, even if under most circumstances it would be. That's @FaheemMitha 's issue.

Comment: @AlanMunn : But pdflatex is returning an error code and that's all latexmk can go on.

Comment: That's not actually how I read the problem. `latexmk` is reading the "No pages of output" as an error, but in this case it's not. The simple document `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}\end{document}` surely doesn't cause `pdflatex` to generate an error. But it does report this as "No pages of output". That's not an error, just a statement of what happened. The problem is `latexmk` 's *interpretation* of that statement.

Comment: Actually pdflatex itself does not return an error code in this situation. Latexmk is picking up on the 'No pages of output' line in the .log file, and treats that as an error. One standard case of running pdflatex without generating a .pdf file is with many distributions of latex packages with .ins and .dtx files. To generate the .sty and other files, you can use `pdflatex file.ins`, but there's no .pdf file. So the lack of generation of a .pdf file is not an error in itself, when pdflatex is run for other (side) effects.

Comment: The situation for latexmk is a different than for pdflatex, because latexmk may do further processing on the pdf file, e.g., to view it when the -pv option is used. Even so, it might be worthwhile for me to add an option to latexmk to ignore the lack of an expected output file when that is safe to do so, i.e., when a missing output file is not used in further processing.